# how to create xml file for animation in android for diferrent screen size

Tags: android

I had created a Transform animation in android using xml.I am running it on larger screen. I had set the value for x and y coordinates in the xml itself.It is running fine on larger screen but when I run it on small screen it works according to the coordinates set for larger screen.How do I set my coordinates so that it works for all the screen size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should then put a modified version xml with the same name under drawable-mdpi or drawable-ldpi. Android will find its way to use them.

```
--drawable-hdpi
   -- anim.xml
--drawable-mdpi
   -- anim.xml
--drawable-ldpi
   -- anim.xml
```

:)